# How to get the OID description for OID value?

Tags: cryptography, python-3.7, oid

I have the following code :

```
    from cryptography import x509
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
    from cryptography.x509.oid import _OID_NAMES
    file = open('ToParse.pem',"r")
    file_data = file.read()
    certoparse = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(bytes(file_data,'utf-8'), 
    default_backend())
    signalgo = certoparse.signature_algorithm_oid
    print (signalgo)
```

Print gives me this :

```
    <ObjectIdentifier(oid=1.2.840.113549.1.1.11, name=sha256WithRSAEncryption)>
```

But I'm only intressted in the name so I tried :

```
    print (signalgo.name)
```

But the 'ObjectIdentifier' object has no attribute name id has only dotted_string attribute (oid).

```
    AttributeError: 'ObjectIdentifier' object has no attribute 'name'
    >>> print (signalgo.dotted_string)
    1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
```

My question is : how can I get the description for this OID ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is :

```
print(signalgo._name)
```

I'm sorry, a newbie in python ( figured it out with dir(signalgo)).